# How to assign Assign multiple virtual swtich to VM

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v

In Hyper-V when we create virtual machine we can assign virtual switch to it.

1. Is it Possible to assign two virtual switch to Hyper-V? If so How?
2. If I understand correctly then we can create different type of virual switch. 
   Internal Network
   Private Network
   External Network.
3. I have three VM out of this One VM I want to assign External as well as Internal Network switch. So this VM expose to outside
   network. Other two VM have only Internal network switch. So it does not expose to outside network.

Let me know your comment on suggestion.

I am using Windows 10 and Hyper-V.

Comment: Can i know that why this question get downvote and vote for close ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it and hope that it will useful to community as well.

1. In Virtual Switch Manager Create all switch that you required.
2. After that go to your VM. ( Make sure that VM is not in running state).

   - In this Go to Settings.
   - In this Add Hardware and Select Network Adapter.
   - Select Switch that you have created.
   - By this way you can multiple network adapter to Virtual Machine in Hyper-V.